# Share a continuous value-color mapping across several ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, geom-point, scale-color-manual

I want to make 4 side-by-side scatterplots in ggplot. In each plot, I am coloring the dots by a continuous variable. I would like to have the same values map to the same colors across the four plots so that I can compare the plots and use one common legend. Any suggestions? I tried scale_colour_gradientn() and played around with the "values" arguement but to no avail so far.

Here are the four plots:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(111)
n <- 100
X1 <- rnorm(n, mean=0,sd=2)
X2 <- rnorm(n, mean=0,sd=2)
y <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 10*(X1 > -1) +
             15*(X1 > -1 & X2 > 2), sd=1)
y0 <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 10*(X1 > -1), sd=1)
y40 <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 10*(X1 > -1) +
               40*(X1 > -1 & X2 > 2), sd=1)
y20 <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 20*(X1 > -1) +
               15*(X1 > -1 & X2 > 2), sd=1)

p1 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(8, "BluGrn"))
p2 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y0)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(8, "BluGrn"))
p3 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y40)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(8, "BluGrn"))
p4 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y20)) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(8, "BluGrn"))
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, nrow=2)
```

Any suggestions on how to create a value->color continuous mapping that can be shared across y,y0,y40, and y20 would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Find the limits you need: `lims <- range(c(y, y0, y40, y20))`. Then supply those limits to any scale you want using `limits = lims`.

Comment: Thank you so much! One additional question. In the real plot I am making, the range of y is much smaller than the range of y40. I want to have enough gradient colors in the y-plot to be able to see contrasts while saving the most extreme colors for the y40-plot. Can "limits" be combined with "values" to accomplish this unequal spread? Im still a little confused by "values".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axeman's approach is correct, though I thought it might be helpful to post an approach with patchwork instead of gridExtra. You can use the `&` operator to apply a ggplot object (typically a scale or theme) to all previous plots. To 'collect' guides, they must share the same name, limits, breaks, colours etc., so you'd have to set the `name` argument to override the default.

The `values` argument can indeed be used to control the spread of colours. What is useful to keep in mind is that ggplot2 rescales the values to the [0,1] interval before applying colours and the `values` argument also operates on these rescaled values. With the 8 colours you're picking, they will be located at the positions `scales::rescale(seq(0, 1, length.out = 8))`. To have the middle values lying closer together, you could try something like `values = c(0, seq(0.2, 0.8, length.out = 6), 1)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(111)
n <- 100
X1 <- rnorm(n, mean=0,sd=2)
X2 <- rnorm(n, mean=0,sd=2)
y <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 10*(X1 > -1) +
             15*(X1 > -1 & X2 > 2), sd=1)
y0 <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 10*(X1 > -1), sd=1)
y40 <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 10*(X1 > -1) +
               40*(X1 > -1 & X2 > 2), sd=1)
y20 <- rnorm(100, mean=10*(X1 < -1) - 20*(X1 > -1) +
               15*(X1 > -1 & X2 > 2), sd=1)

p1 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y))
p2 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y0))
p3 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y40))
p4 <- ggplot(data=NULL) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=X2, col=y20))

p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = hcl.colors(8, "BluGrn"),
                         limits = range(y, y0, y40, y20),
                         values = c(0, seq(0.2, 0.8, length.out = 6), 1),
                         name = "Values")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>